# Synchronize date format between rails i18n and bootstrap datepicker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, bootstrap-datepicker

The bootstrap date picker requires date format as:

```
mm/dd/yyyy
```

but Rails i18n format is defined as:

```
%m/%d/%Y
```

My website has many different translations. I would like to define the date format in the Rails i18n format and pass it to the date picker so that I only define a date format once per locale.

I can retrieve the current locale's date format using:

```
I18n.translate('date.formats.default')
```

Is there a simple way to convert %m/%d/%Y to mm/dd/yyyy so that it can be used with the date picker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap date picker can be configured with the required format:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
```

I recommend setting up a required datepicker [format](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) which is specific to each language:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
pirate:
time:
  formats:
    short: "%m/%d/%y"
    datepicker: "mm/dd/yyyy"
```

You should then be able to pass this to the Datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: <%= I18n.t 'time.formats.datepicker' %>
});
```

Ideally you'd want the datepicker to submit the datetime in the same format, regardless of how it's displayed to the user. Look at [the bootstrap format api doc](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#format) for information on supplying different display and (submitted) value